# C# event Click TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a usercontrol inheriting TextBox. But somehow the click event does not work. Other events work. How to make that work click?

```
  this.Click += new EventHandler(AfyTransparentTextBox_Click);

    private void AfyTransparentTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KY-KY");
    }
```

Comment: Please give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (It shouldn't need to be more than about 30 lines...)

Comment: This work and I see KY-KY.  this.KeyPress +=new KeyPressEventHandler(AfyTransparentTextBox_KeyPress);

Comment: Where is this code? on the form if so then this.Click is the forms click event.

Comment: Are you really clicking the Textbox or you're only "putting" the cursor in the textbox.....yes it sound odd, but it works for me if I do click the control

Comment: This code in public partial class AfyTransparentTextBox : TextBox

Comment: If the textbox is transparent IE might not capture the click event, maybe that is the case. Try to remove the transparency and confirm that click event is still not working.

Comment: Are there any child controls overlaying the `TextBox`? Where are you registering the event handler? Also, because you're an inheriting sub-class, you should ideally put the event handling logic in an override `protected override void OnClock(EventArgs e)`

Comment: I believe you should use the OnClick method from inside a textBox derided class.

Comment: @adolfy: You still haven't shown a short but *complete* program demonstrating the program. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be appropriate in your scenario but it works:

```
public class AfyTransparentTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("KY-KY");

        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked MSDN; TextBox doesn't have an `OnClick`.

Comment: But the control TextBox derives from.

Comment: Are you sure about that? MSDN doesn't mention `Form` anywhere in the inheritance hierarchy and if I change the method to `OnClick` I get an error - "No suitable method found to override". Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Pressumably. We are talking about a TextBox and a TextBox in Winforms derives from Control. And Control defines OnClick.

Comment: @Jason D see link for information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake. I was looking at the version in `System.Windows.Controls` which doesn't have `OnClick`. I guess it depends if the OP is using WinForms or WPF. Either way, he should be able to get the idea.

Comment: The question is tagged with winforms. So throw out the wpf part an simply use OnClick as example. Is there even a difference in the code?

Comment: Oops, that's embarrassing. I completely neglected to read the tags. Anyways, the answer should be correct now.

Comment: OnClick only has the EventArgs argument, not the MouseButtonEventArgs.  You probably should have the override method still call `base.OnClick(e);` as well.

Comment: So few lines of code but so much trouble :) To fix your mood, the idea to override the method and not handling own events it absolute the right thing to do. I voted for it ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. Today's just one of those days.